# Limit of the sequence $2^n|\cos n|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I try to find the following limit :
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty,n\in\mathbb{N}}2^n |\cos(n)|.$$
If the limit was on the reals number, it's easy to show that it is undetermined, because of the cosinus being zero periodically. I try to show that it's also undetermined with $n$ integer. It has been done with $n|\cos n|$ (math.stackexchange.com/q/3670996/42969) but I can't adapt the argument here, because of the $2^n$.
I made a table on mathematica and it seems to tends to $\infty$ because of the $2^n$ growing sufficiently fast.
Does someone have an idea on showing the undetermination or the convergence to $\infty$ ? Thank's a lot.

Comment: The limit can't be $\infty$ because there are infinitely many negative numbers in this sequence.

Comment: Hint: infinitely many $n$ have $\cos(n) > \frac12$ (at least one in every seven, in fact more) and similarly infinitely many $n$ have $\cos(n) < -\frac12$.

Comment: The limit does not exist. The sequence of $cos(n)$ is sometimes positive, sometimes negative (though not periodically so).

Comment: By $\infty$, I mean the absolute value of this tending to $+\infty$.